# Combining animations of moving a block behind the cursor and updating a sprite on a block

Tags: javascript, jquery

Faced such a task, where you need to combine 2 animations. 1 animation to move the block behind the cursor inside the container, and 2 animation to update the sprite on this block.

Let me tell you more about my problem. The block must move if the cursor is inside the container, if it is outside the container, then the animation stops. 2 sprite update animation is only triggered when the block is moved.

I have no idea how to stop the animation of the sprite when the cursor is outside of the container. So I really need any help

***block movement animation behind the cursor***

```
        let block = $(".block"), container = $(".container");
        let mouseX = 0, limitX = container.width() - block.width();
        let blockX = 0;

        // когда курсор на футере
        container.on('mousemove', function(e) {
            mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - container.offset().left, limitX);
            if(mouseX > limitX){ mouseX = limitX;}
        });

        container.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
            mouseX = 0;
        });

        
        startAnimation();
        let loop = setInterval(function(){
            let newBlockX = peopleX + ((mouseX - blockX) / 20);

            if(blockX < newBlockX || blockX == 0){ block.removeClass('forward'); }
            else{ block.addClass('forward'); }

            blockX = newBlockX;
            block.css({left:peopleX});
        }, 10);
```

***sprite update animation***

```
    let animationInterval;

    function stopAnimation() {
        clearInterval(animationInterval);
        animationInterval = null;
    }

    function startAnimation() {
        let widthOfSpriteSheet = 140;
        let widthOfEachSprite = 35;

        const speed = 120;
        let position = widthOfEachSprite;
        const diff = widthOfEachSprite;
        animationInterval = setInterval(() => {
            $(".people, .preloader-image").css({backgroundPosition: `0px -${position}px`});
            if (position < widthOfSpriteSheet) {
                position = position + diff;
            } else {
                position = widthOfEachSprite;
            }
        }, speed);
    }
```

Comment: Make a reproductible exemple will help us to understand better

Comment: dose the ```mouseleave``` event fire you move out of the container, is so would you simply not just need to call ```clearInterval(animationInterval);``` and ```clearInterval(loop );``` in that method to stop the intervals that do the animation an then re apply them on ```mouseenter```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it looks like you do not need a `setInterval`, what you need to do is just listen to `mousemove` and then apply changes to sprite and box (look at the snippet):

```
container.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  moveSprite();
  moveBox(e.pageX);
});
```

In a case you still need to use `setInterval` then listen to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to control the animation, for example:

```
container.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  startAnimation();
});
container.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
  stopAnimation();
});
```

```js
let block = $(".block"), container = $(".container");
let mouseX = 0, limitX = container.width() - block.width();
let blockX = 0;
let peopleX = 10;
let widthOfSpriteSheet = 200;
let widthOfEachSprite = 10;
let position = widthOfEachSprite;
let diff = widthOfEachSprite;

function moveSprite() {
    $(".people").css({backgroundPosition: `0px -${position}px`});
    if (position < widthOfSpriteSheet) {
        position = position + diff;
    } else {
        position = widthOfEachSprite;
    }
}

function moveBox(pageX) {
  mouseX = Math.min(pageX - container.offset().left, limitX);
  if(mouseX > limitX){ mouseX = limitX;}
  let newBlockX = Math.trunc(peopleX + ((mouseX - blockX) / 10));

  if (blockX < newBlockX || blockX == 0){ block.removeClass('forward'); }
  else if (blockX > newBlockX) { block.addClass('forward'); }

  blockX = newBlockX;
  block.css({left:blockX});
}

container.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  moveSprite();
  moveBox(e.pageX);
});
```

```css
.people {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/200');
}

.block {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  position: absolute;
}
.block.forward {
  background: green;
}

.container {
  margin: 10px 5px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="people"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```